# Formula to identify where there is a value for '0' and '1' per date in Excel pivot table

Tags: date, datetime-format

I am analysing camera trap data looking at nocturnal denning sites. I have formatted my data so that I have a '0' value and an '1' per date when there is an animal entering and leaving a den site on the same day (ie; one 'sleep event'). I am currently manually going through my pivot tables counting each occasion where there is both an entering (0) and exiting (1) event on the same day to count how many times an animal 'slept' in the den site. Im hoping there is a quicker way but have no idea how to do that...
This is what my pivot table looks like:

[image]

Any assistance would be appreciated :)

I am currently manually counting 'sleep events'

Comment: Just set up another column which gets a 1 if the dates on that row and the previous row are equal, _and_ the indicator values for those two rows are not equal. That gives you a "tick" for every transition. Then you can sum that column. If you only want transitions in one direction, you can instead test for a specific value instead of non-equality (_e.g._ previous row is 0 and current row is 1 means the [wretched creature](https://teara.govt.nz/en/possums/page-4) has escaped death and re-entered its lair of evil).

Comment: Thanks for  your advice :), thats what im trying to do but I cant seem to figure out a formula/code that can do that, any ideas?

Comment: This is rudimentary spreadsheet stuff. Familiarize yourself with the documentation on constructing formulas and referencing cells. Let's say your date is in column A and count is column B. Then you want something like `A1 == A2 AND B1 == 0 AND B2 == 1`. Imaginary syntax of course. I don't use Excel. That'll give you a true or false value. I'm sure there's some kind of `IF` operator that can take an expression and then produce a value, like `IF(expr, 1, 0)`. If you're doing all of this in a pivot table, then I really have no idea. Never used those either. Might be better to ask on superuser.com

Comment: Thank you for your comments :) I think i will have to ask elsewhere specific to pivot tables because whilst I know rudimentary spreadsheet stuff, this is slightly different :)

Comment: Yeah, it also has almost nothing to do with programming, so is not particularly on-topic for Stack Overflow. That's why I suggested Super User.

Comment: Best of luck with the possum tracking! You probably don't wanna know how many of those things I've personally exterminated. Hopefully wherever you live they're not an invasive pest species on the government hit-list.